# how to find sum of entire column data in pyspark RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, rdd

I have tab delimited text data with 5 columns, i need to find out sum of 4th column.

```
# Find the total sales values:

from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

if __name__ == '__main__':
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("sales").setMaster("local[2]")

    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

    sales = sc.textFile("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Retail_Sample_Data_Set.txt")
    result = sales.map(lambda line: line.split("\t")[4])
```

i used sum () and reduce by key but nothing work for me. Please help me out ?

Comment: I would suggest to use dataframe apis

Answer (score 1):

Your lambda in `map` transformation is returning a string. You may need to use typecast. For example, if the 5th column is an `int`, change the lambda in your `map` to `lambda line: int(line.split("\t")[4])` or if it is a `float`, then `lambda line: float(line.split("\t")[4])`.